# SPICE Programs worth learning for

Tags: analog, design, spice

I was wondering what are the professional SPICE programs for simulating analog circuits in the industry now. For example, where the big companies like Atmel simulate their microcontrollers, or a company like Texas Instruments simulates their op amp design. Also, which programs you would suggest to an electrical and electronics engineering student to learn for analog circuit design bearing transistors that make him ready for professional life.
I would be glad if people with experience answer this question. Thank you.

Comment: Develop the ability to look at a circuit and see how it works. That is far more important than learning any particular tool.

Comment: Not a complete answer, but regarding digital chips (microcontrollers, etc): on the transistor level these may be modelled with SPICE, but for the overall design of digital ICs, a hardware description language such as VHDL or Verilog is used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many large semiconductor companies have in-house developed and enhanced versions of SPICE -- e.g. see [in-house SPICE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SPICE). These typically support the more complex needs of high performance and high volume IC designs. Other companies frequently just use the simulator that comes with their EDA tools.

Enhancements to SPICE might include support for specialized device models, significantly higher speed and new algorithms for convergence, large circuits or new simulation options.

Answer (score 2):

@jp314 answered how the big companies use SPICE, often with tools that aren't publicly available.  As a student, [LTspice](http://www.linear.com/designtools/software/) isn't a bad way to start.  It's cross platform (including Mac) and uses fairly standard SPICE syntax.  It's also free.